# How to list rows data using PHP

Tags: php, forms, row

I've got a HTML form divided into 3 sections (tables). When I submit the form, it has to go through PHP script in gen-czk-pdf.php cause of transfering HTML to PDF. Each table will have undetermined number of rows and I need advice from you, how do I list all these rows from each table using PHP.

This is shorted table example in calculate.php file...

```
<form action="gen-czk-pdf.php" method="get" id="data" name="data">

<table class="items-table material-table" id="materialTable">
<tr>
<td><textarea rows="2" id="materialItemName"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" id="materialUnitPrice" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="materialItemQuantity" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="materialItemCoeff" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="materialItemPriceNoVat" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="materialItemVat" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="materialItemPriceInVat" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

getting variables in gen-czk-pdf.php

```
$matName = $_GET['materialItemName'];
$matPrPer = $_GET['materialUnitPrice'];
$matQuant = $_GET['materialItemQuantity'];
$matUnit = $_GET['materialUnitType'];
$matCoeff = $_GET['materialItemCoeff'];
$matItPrNoVat = $_GET['materialItemPriceNoVat'];
$matItVat = $_GET['materialItemVat'];
$matItPrInVat = $_GET['materialItemPriceInVat'];
```

So this is one row of the first section and I need a script, which list all rows of one section (table).

Comment: do you mean this input will be generated into PDF...and your asking how to get the html data to php? am i right?

Comment: No, my question is, how to list each row of the table using variables. Is there some posibility? At the table will be non specified number of rows

Comment: you mean you will get data in database and will show it in table?

Comment: Actually im not using database, i have a form, submit it and the script using pdf lib creates PDF. And i dont know how to list all rows in form, because the user could add or remove rows. So this is my problem which maybe kill me :/

Comment: so you want to copy the form convert to pdf as look alike?

Comment: Yes, i want to copy inserted data, send them to gen-czk-pdf.php, and in this file i have to write script which lists all rows, is it understandable? Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you helped me with that. As I can see, your probably alone about that

Comment: kindly check and up it if my codes help's you

Comment: Your code looks great, but Im using TCPDF library and as I said Im beginner with php, so im confused now, very confused...

Comment: Im sorry for loosing your time, i know its my fault, but its hard for me.. Thank you very much, i will try hard

Comment: ohh sorry i thought your using also codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dompdf_gen {

    public function __construct() {

        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

        $pdf = new DOMPDF();

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->dompdf = $pdf;

    }

}
```

Controller:

```
function pdf(){
             $container = array($matName => $_GET['materialItemName'],
                               $matPrPer => $_GET['materialUnitPrice'],
                               .....and next and next
                 );
                   $data['transfer_data'] = $container;
                $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
                $html = $this->load->view('contracts/gen-czk-pdf', $data, true);//change the "contracts" to the folder where the " gen-czk-pdf" contained
                $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
                $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
                // Convert to PDF
                $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
                $this->dompdf->render();
                $this->dompdf->stream("Contract.pdf",array("Attachment"=>0)); // VIEW IN OTHER TAB
                //$this->dompdf->stream("Contract.pdf"); // SAVE FILE TO DISK
        }
```

VIEW:

```
<table class="items-table material-table" id="materialTable">
 <?php foreach($transfer_data as $data) : ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?=$data->materialItemName;?></td>
   <td><?=$data->materialUnitPrice;?></td>
   .............
  </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

...I think i will give you idea on my codes

Answer (score 0):

change your form to this.

```
<form action="gen-czk-pdf.php" method="get" id="data" name="data">

<table class="items-table material-table" id="materialTable">
<tr>
<td><textarea rows="2" name="item[][materialItemName]"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" name="item[][materialUnitPrice]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="item[][materialItemQuantity]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="item[][materialItemCoeff]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="item[][materialItemPriceNoVat]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="item[][materialItemVat]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="item[][materialItemPriceInVat]" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

getting variables in gen-czk-pdf.php

```
$item = $_POST['item']
foreach($item as $i)   // iterate depend on how many table you put inside <form>
{
   //$i == array of inputs 
   //      array(
   //            'materialItemName' => some value,
   //            'materialUnitPrice' => some value,
   //            ...
   //           )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For listing rows data just:
- GRAB VARS

```
$matn = $_GET['materialItemName'];
$matup = $_GET['materialUnitPrice'];
$matq = $_GET['materialItemQuantity'];
$matut = $_GET['materialUnitType'];
$matic = $_GET['materialItemCoeff'];
$matipnv = $_GET['materialItemPriceNoVat'];
$mativ = $_GET['materialItemVat'];
$matisv = $_GET['materialItemSumVat'];
$matipiv = $_GET['materialPriceInVat'];
```

- AND TYPE SOMETHING LIKE THIS

```
$material_listing_data = '';
foreach( $matn as $key => $matn ) {
  $material_listing_data = "<table><tr><td>".
    $matn."</td><td>".
        $matup[$key]."</td><td>".
        $matq[$key]."</td><td>".
        $matut[$key]."</td><td>".
        $matic[$key]."</td></tr><tr><td>".
        $matipnv[$key]."</td><td>".
        $mativ[$key]."</td><td>".
        $matisv[$key]."</td><td>".
        $matipiv[$key]."</td></tr></table>
        <br />";
   }

$pdf->writeHTML($material_listing_data, true, false, true, false, '');
```